# Large number of mat-tooltip inside mat-table slows application

Tags: angular, performance, angular-material, angular6

We have been implementing grid using `mat-table` and for each cell, there is a `mat-tooltip`. As far as I know, tool-tip renders for each cell even though user will hover over it or not. see the sample code for usage of tooltip.

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="carrier">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header class="clm-carrier">Carrier</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" matTooltip="{{element.carrier}}" class="clm-carrier">{{element.carrier}}</td>
</ng-container>
```

I found somewhere that tool-tip may impact your performance if there are large number of it. We have around 500 rows in 3 different table and min 5 column in each. so almost `500 * 5 * 5 * 5 = 62500` max can be render at any time and which may be overhead in production.

Is this really problem with that? Does material angular works different in terms of rendering. Does rendering large number of tooltip is feasible even if with mat-tooltip? What could be done to improve this?

Answer (score 2):

you can try simple html title attribute to show tooltip for large number of tooltips to be rendered.

Use
`title="{{element.carrier}}"`
instead
`matTooltip="{{element.carrier}}"`

Comment: I doubt, it will make it more slower.

Comment: I use it for some cases. I was also facing slowness while using matTooltip then I changed it to title.Now its working well

Answer (score 0):

Decisively 62500 `mat-tooltip` renders could impact performance. Maybe consider implement pagination to your table?

Comment: So maybe [popover](https://github.com/ncstate-sat/popover) instead `mat-tooltip`? It's flexible and easy to implemenent, based on `cdkOverlay`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use virtual scrolling only the tooltips in the view port will be rendered which will reduce the performance impact.

check this.

https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview